# Warning about grub bootlaoder

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I'm installing Debian in VirtualBox and get the following message:
'Loading grub boot loader on hard disk'.
OK, Enter and up to the following message which goes like this:
'It looks like this new installation (i.e. Debian, jeegee) is the only OS on this computer. If this is the case you can install the grub boot loader in the master boot record of your first hard disk without any problem'.
Well: 1. Debian is not the only OS on my computer, which runs on Ubuntu. 2. Which one is my 'first hard disk'? (I have one hard disk).

The following warning puzzles me more: 'If the installation program (of Debian, jeegee) doesn't succeed in detecting an other OS on your computer, adapting the master boot record (see above, jeegee) can have the effect that this OS can not be started temporarily.
You can always manually install the grub later to start this system again'.

I am new in these matters, but I feel there are inconsistencies in this information.
Hope to get some support here!

Comment: Sorry any OS other then Ubuntu is off topic here.

Comment: As far as the VirtualBox guest goes, it correctly believes that it is the only OS on the Virtual hard disk. That is what VB does --- it creates a Virtual machine using a separate OS from the host using a virtual hard disk created by VB. This makes the VB guest believe that it is the actual (main) computer.

Comment: Hi Eagle_Mike, thanks a lot for your reply!    I have also installed Windows 10 and Xubuntu on VBox. Windows 10 runs smoothly, but Xubuntu is very slow, close to freezing. What could be the reason?